# profile page not working with session id

Tags: php, mysql, session

i am creating a profile page and a login page where i store the session id and then in the profile file i check if isset or not but the problem that i get is that the system always display an error message  and i used **print_r($_SESSION);** the browser display :

**Important data are missingArray ( [first_name] => [email] => )**

how to fix this error?????

## login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('include/connect.php');
$message = ""; 
if(!empty($_POST['email']))
{

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$email = strip_tags($email);
$pass = strip_tags($pass);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
//$pass = md5($pass);

$sql=mysql_query( "SELECT user_id, email_address, first_name FROM user WHERE email_address='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1") or die("error in user table");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($login_check > 0)
  {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

          $id = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;

          $firstname = $row['first_name'];
          $_SESSION['first_name']= $firstname;

          $email = $row['email_address'];
          $_SESSION['email_address']= $email;

          mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_log_date=now() WHERE user_id='$id'");

          header("Location: profile.php");    
  }//close if 
  else
  {
      $message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
      //exit();
  }
}//close if

?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>RegisterPage</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

</head>

<body>


       <div id="loginborder">
         <p  style="color:#FF0000" align="left"><?php print("$message") ?></p>

         <!--Login form where user submit his registered email and password-->
         <form action="login.php" method="post">
           email-address:<br />
           <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" />
           <br />
           <br />
           Password:<br />
           <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
           <br />
           <br />
           <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
           <a href="register.php" style="position: absolute; top: 132px; left: 61px;"> <strong> Register</strong></a>
         </form>
       </div>
```

## profile.php

```
   <?php
session_start();
 require_once('include/connect.php'); 


if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['user_id'];
    var_dump($id);

}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

else
{
    print "Important  data  are missing";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    exit();

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user  WHERE user_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

   $firstname=$row['first_name'];
   $lastname=$row['last_name'];
   $birth_date=$row['birth_date'];
   $registered_date=$row['registered_date'];
   //***************for upload img*****************//
   $check_pic="members/$id/image01.jpg";
   $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
   if(file_exists($check_pic))
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"100px\"/>";
   }
   else
   {
       $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\">";
   }
   echo $id, $firstname, $birth_date;
?>
```

Comment: You only select the user_id when you are creating the session, I guess the error is from there "SELECT user_id FROM user" => "SELECT user_id, first_name, email FROM user"

Comment: you mean i must select also the user_id???

Comment: No, when you set your session, you use $row['first_name'] and $row['email'] but they are not returned in your row because you just take the user_id from the SELECT, am I right ?

Comment: yess i am taking only the user_id

Comment: Also change  $id=$_SESSION['user_id']; to $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;

Comment: ok now it take the email addres and the first name but still displaying the error messgae about the session user_id

Comment: Read my last comment ;)

Comment: ok now when i submit the login it still in the same page without displaying or changing anything else

Comment: Are you on the profile page ? If yes, do an echo at the end of your loop to see if you are connected

Comment: An other thing is that you don't need to use "while" here because you select and return a LIMIT 1 $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) should work without loop.

Comment: No when i submit the login button it still in the index.php  how to fix this ??

Comment: WHat is the link of your form ? (action)

Comment: <form action="login.php" method="post"> thank you for helping me but i really need help and you are the only person until now that help me

Comment: Your form should go to login.php except if you redirect in your connect.php

Comment: no i am not redirect in the connect.php    i will edit my question and submit the new code in the profile and login maybe this will help you to help me ;)

Comment: i did this in the login .php   **$message = "correct email and passworddd!!";  
   // header("Location: profile.php");**   and the sbrowser display the message    so i think the problem is in the redirection????

Comment: remove the $message and add after header() => exit();

Comment: sorry i did not understand what i must do i did remove the $ message but what about the second part of the answer???

Comment: You have to add exit(); after the header() line

Comment: annn ok i did as you said but still nothing change it still no displaying for the profile page

Comment: ob_start();header("Location: profile.php");ob_end_flush();

Comment: try this instead of only use header location

Comment: i tried these but still the same problemmmmmmm

Comment: can you validate my answer below please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to changes several things

First : get first_name and email in your request

```
'SELECT user_id,email,first_name FROM user WHERE email_address='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1'
```

Second, remove while loop and do

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

You are limiting to 1 result so no need to loop inside result

Change `$id=$_SESSION['user_id'];` to `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;`

Also, limit to 1 the result from profile and remove loop (user_id => UNIQUE => LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is just store a value in a session variable [$_SESSION['username']] after everything checks out then select the data from the mysql table using the value in the session

----------------------------------for example------------------------------------------------------

on login.php

```
if($login_check > 0)
{
  $_SESSION['email']=$email;//storing variable in SESSION
 header("Location: profile.php");    
}
else
{
  $message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
  die();// kill the script
}
```

on profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();// start session
require_once('include/connect.php'); //include connection file

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user  WHERE email='(mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email']))'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
// then just echo all the data you need
?>
```